# How can i find the last key of an array where can be found a value from another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array that has some sql operators:

```
Array
(
    [0] => =
    [1] => <
    [2] => >
    [3] => !=
    [4] => <>
    [5] => >=
    [6] => <=
)
```

And this array that is a preg_split of an sql statement:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => =
            [1] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Emma'
            [1] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => AND
            [1] => 14
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => age
            [1] => 18
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => <=
            [1] => 22
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => '21'
            [1] => 25
        )

)
```

In second array at [5][0] i have a '<=' operator that can be found at [6] in that first array(that contains the sql operators). Now this is not a static statement, sometimes i might want to use '=' or '>' instead of '<='.

Is there a way to dynamically determine where the last operator can be found in this statement array?

Thank you!:D

Comment: So as a result you want `5`?  Is the second array always `0` based and sequential?

Comment: So as a result you want `22` for the example given? Always the latest operator position?

Comment: For the example given i want to get that `5` and yes the first array is always `0` :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last position of an operator and the last operator from all matches returned by the split operation:

```
$lastIndex = null;
$lastPosition = null;
$lastOperator = null;

foreach ($matches as $index => $match) {
    $isOperator = in_array($match[0], $operators, true);
    if ($isOperator) {
        $lastIndex = $index;
        $lastPosition = $match[1];
        $lastOperator = array_keys($operators, $match[0])[0];
    }
}

var_dump($lastIndex, $lastPosition, $lastOperator);
```

Comment: Hey hakre! Thank you so much yet i have a small question, it works just fine, but in this example how do i get that `5` not that `22`? :-s

Comment: `$lastOperator` should have the 22 doesn't it? (excuse my lack of having this example code tested.)

Comment: It has it but i don't need that 22(i'll only use it for later) what i need is that little `5` - sorry for insisting that much on it:D

Comment: O my god, thank you soooo muchhhh! It works just perfect :D <3 <3

Answer (score 1):

Extract the `0` column and search:

```
$result = array_search($first_array[6], array_column($second_array, 0));
```

Comment: Hey! So i've got key [5], it worked but now how do i make it dynamic? cause it won't be the same operator everytime :-s -  Thank you!!!

Comment: Alternative for array_search: array_keys w/ second search parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I misunderstood your question. Now it does exactly what you want:

```
    <?php
        $operators= array(
            '=',
            '<',
            '>',
            '!=',
            '<>',
            '>=',
            '<=',
        );

        $statement = array(
            array("name",   0),
            array("=",      5),
            array("Emma",   7),
            array("AND",    14),
            array("age",    18),
            array("<=",     22),
            array("21",     25)
        );


        $result = find_last_operator($statement,$operators);
        echo $result; //output: 5

        function find_last_operator($statement, $operators) {
            for($key=count($statement)-1;$key > -1; --$key) {
               if (array_search($statement[$key][0],$operators) !== true ) return $key; 
            }
         }
    ?>
```

Output: 5

Test it online [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b438d2604677ed366fba985fbbdadc28ff8bdcd)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do this:

```
foreach (array_reverse($statement, true) as $key => $segment)
  if (in_array($segment[0], $operators))
    return print($key);
```

EDIT: this way it's faster, it won't loop thru all of it. array_reverse(..., true) will preserve the keys.